# What is context? Why use in odoo?

Tags: python, odoo-9

What is context means in odoo ?  Please give any example for explanation

```
def change_product_qty(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    """ Changes the Product Quantity by making a Physical Inventory. """
    if context is None:
        context = {}

    inventory_obj = self.pool.get('stock.inventory')
    inventory_line_obj = self.pool.get('stock.inventory.line')

    for data in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
        if data.new_quantity < 0:
            raise UserError(_('Quantity cannot be negative.'))
        ctx = context.copy()
        ctx['location'] = data.location_id.id
        ctx['lot_id'] = data.lot_id.id
        if data.product_id.id and data.lot_id.id:
            filter = 'none'
        elif data.product_id.id:
            filter = 'product'
        else:
            filter = 'none'
        inventory_id = inventory_obj.create(cr, uid, {
            'name': _('INV: %s') % tools.ustr(data.product_id.name),
            'filter': filter,
            'product_id': data.product_id.id,
            'location_id': data.location_id.id,
            'lot_id': data.lot_id.id}, context=context)

        line_data = self._prepare_inventory_line(cr, uid, inventory_id, data, context=context)

        inventory_line_obj.create(cr, uid, line_data, context=context)
        inventory_obj.action_done(cr, uid, [inventory_id], context=context)
    return {}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Context  is dictionary containing logged in user ID, language, time zone, and potentially any key Value pair which has been added. It is meant as a means of passing data between models and views. In Android it is similar to passing a parcel of data when starting an intent or activity.